# Is it possible to pair the affiliation history with a year in which a researcher served in given institution, as it appears in the scopus website?

Tags: scopus, pybliometrics

I used au.affiliation_history to get the affiliation history from a list of Authors ID.  It worked great but now I am trying to pair the affiliation history with the Year in which the researcher served in the institution that appear in the affiliation history results.

However, I cannot find the way to do this. Is is possible to do this? If so,  can you please give me a hint or idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the information Scopus shares on an author profile on scopus.com is not the same they share via the Author Retrieval API. I think the only way to get to yearly affiliations is to extract them from the publications that you get from the Scopus Search API.

```
from collections import defaultdict

from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

AUTHOR = "7004212771"

q = f"AU-ID({AUTHOR})"
s = ScopusSearch(q)

yearly_affs = defaultdict(lambda: list())
for pub in s.results:
    year = pub.coverDate[:4]
    auth_idx = pub.author_ids.split(";").index(AUTHOR)
    affs = pub.author_afids.split(";")[auth_idx].split("-")
    yearly_affs[year].extend(affs)
```

`yearly_affs` then contains a *list* of all affiliations recorded in publications for that year.

Naturally, the list will contain duplicates. If you don't like that, use `set()` and `update()` instead.

The `.split("-")` part for `affs` is for multiple affiliations (when the researcher reports multiple affiliations on a paper. You might want to use the first reported instead. Then use `[0]` at the end and `append()` in the next row.

Also, there will likely be gaps. I recommend turning the `yearly_affs` into a pandas DataFrame, select for each year the main affiliation, and then fill gaps forward or backward.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works well at the individual level, but when I pass a list of AUTHORS_IDS  I get this message "Scopus400Error: Error translating query". I think this happens when within the list there are AUTHORS with no multiple affiliations. Any Idea how to make it work for both in the same call?

Comment: For multiple ones, your query needs to look differently, as in the advanced document search: `AU-ID(57209617104) OR AU-ID(7004212771)`. But in this case your loop will look different, because it has to accommodate multiple possible IDs.
I suggest to loop over author IDs instead: You create a list of author IDs, and put everything that I wrote on top into the loop

Comment: I have been trying to apply your solution but after trying multiple times I haven't 100% get it right. until the year =, I have it right, Could you give me a help?                                                            for ele in AUTHOR: 
    q = f"AU-ID({ele})"
    s = ScopusSearch(q)
    yearly_affs = defaultdict(lambda: list())
    for ele in s.results:
        year = ele.coverDate[:4]
        auth_idx = ele.author_ids.split(";").index(AUTHOR)
        affs = ele.author_afids.split(";")[auth_idx].split("-")
        yearly_affs[year].extend(affs)

Comment: Assuming that `AUTHOR` is a list, you obviously have to define a container _outside_ the outmost loop OR write out the results from `yearly_affs` at the end of each outer loop iteration.